# Protect c++ dll file on hard disk

Tags: c++, file, security, dll, loadlibrary

I want to load dll from hard disk using LoadLibrary(). But want to protect dll during loading. So no one can open or copy or delete dll file from hard disk until I finish my process.

Comment: Windows does not allow to delete files that are in-use anyway

Comment: yup, so whats about open and copy

Comment: Haven't tried myself, but did you have a look at [`LockFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: i will change (decryption) in dll during execution and i do not want the user to get the file during execution